# Python Generate New List of Repeated Values per 2 Lists

Tags: list, python-3.x

Given these lists:

```
a=[0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
b=['r','b','g','y','o','p']
```

I'd like another list that repeats elements in list b based on the frequency of  values in list a like this:

```
c = ['r','b','b','b','g','g','g','g','g']
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Shouldn't `y` be `g` in the output?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I've corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume the entries in `a` are indices, the following should work and is relatively self-explanatory.

```
c = [b[i] for i in a]
# ['r', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g']
```